# Scalable div larger than window

Tags: html, css

**Concept**

I'm trying to get a list larger than the window, which will move depending on mouse position. The goal is to allow the user to see all list entries, whatever their amount.

Below is a simple image to illustrate the concept :

- Black frame is the window
- Black arrow is the mouse position
- Red line is the list

[image]

**Problem**

Currently, I can make this work only if I set the list width. I would like to **not** set this width.

Here's the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    var widthPage = $('.strip').width(); 
    var widthStrip = $('.strip ul').width();
    
    $('.strip').on('mousemove', function(event) {
        var offset = $(this).offset(); 
        var relX = event.pageX - offset.left;
        var left = relX * (widthStrip - widthPage) / widthPage;
        $(this).find('ul').css('left', '-'+left+'px');
    });
    
});
```

```css
/* Positioning */
.strip {
    position:relative;  
    overflow: hidden;
}
.strip ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 1750px;
}
.strip li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

/* Style */
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.strip {
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
.strip ul {
    height: 30px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.strip li {
    list-style: none;
    border: 1px solid #EBEBEB;
    margin-right: -1px;
    padding: 0 5px;
    line-height: 28px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="strip">
    <ul>
        <li>Lorem</li>
        <li>Ipsum</li>
        <li>Dolor</li>
        <li>Sit</li>
        <li>Amet</li>
        <li>Consectetur</li>
        <li>Adipisicing</li>
        <li>Elit</li>
        <li>Sed</li>
        <li>Do</li>
        <li>Eiusmod</li>
        <li>Tempor</li>
        <li>Incididunt</li>
        <li>Ut</li>
        <li>Labore</li>
        <li>Et</li>
        <li>Dolore</li>
        <li>Magna</li>
        <li>Aliqua</li>
        <li>Ut</li>
        <li>Enim</li>
        <li>Ad</li>
        <li>Minim</li>
        <li>Veniam</li>
        <li>Quis</li>
        <li>Nostrud</li>
        <li>Exercitation</li>
        <li>Ullamco</li>
        <li>Laboris</li>
        <li>Nisi</li>
        <li>Ut</li>
        <li>Aliquip</li>
        <li>Ex</li>
        <li>Ea</li>
        <li>Commodo</li>
        <li>Consequat</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is that to force the floated elements to expand beyond the page's width, you need to force their container to have a width sufficient to hold them all. I propose using `display: inline-block` instead, as they will continue so long as their container specifies `white-space: nowrap`.

```
.strip {
    position:relative;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.strip ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    font-size: 0; /* prevent html whitespace from displaying */
}
.strip li {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px; /* reset font size so the elements appear */
}
```

After setting these styles, [the list will scroll correctly without an explicit width set](http://jsfiddle.net/WWdFy/6/).

Comment: Interesting... I thought of all those issues, tried them but didnt work properly... Not sure where I went wrong.. I probably didnt have the nowrap when I replaced the `float` with `inline-block` :) gj

Comment: @GiovanniSilveira Probably. Without `white-space: nowrap`, `inline-block` elements will simply wrap around like floated elements instead of breaking out of their containers.

Comment: Yes, I know... I was just going <kbd>ctrl-z</kbd> on my stuff to try different things... I was sure I tried both together, I guess I might have went back a bit too much and removed it... Either that or I had some additional crap I tried there that screwed it up :)

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be to make `.strip` very large and change `widthPage` to a grandparent's width who's size is equivalent to the original parent's, in this case `var widthPage = window.innerWidth;`

[**Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/WWdFy/8/)

Changed CSS

```
body { overflow-x: hidden; }
.strip {
    position:relative;  
    overflow: hidden;
    width:10000px; /* Arbitrary large value */
}
.strip ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this working alternative. Full-CSS solution got my preference, but +1 anyway.

Comment: Sure, I agree. However if you were in need of keeping `display:block` for some odd reason or keep whitespace this would be the only way to go ^^